# how to return different things in function in Julia

Tags: julia

Like the simplified function below, if `b<c` then how can I get the result "No"?

```
function o(b,c)
    if b>=c        
        return b,c,b+c
    else
        return "No"
    end
end
b = 3
c = 4
k,h,l = o(b,c)
```

Comment: just write `x = o(b,c)' and you will get a string `"No"` or a tuple having three elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real problem is that you are returning two completely different things. In one case 3 different variables assigned to integers, in the other case 1 string.

The function is actually working here. The specific error you get is because you are trying to assign 3 variables to one string. When you assign multiple variables to a string, julia actually splits the string up into characters and assign a character to each variable, but your string is only 2 characters long and you are assigning 3 variables.

You should try and have your function return objects of the same type, or at the least the same number of variables. If you insist on getting this function to work in something resembling it's current form then you could do something like this

```
function o(b,c)
    if b>=c        
        return [b,c,b+c]
    else
        return "No"
    end
end
b = 5
c = 4
result = o(b,c)
```